# How to make map.flyTo on JS with a HTML <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, api, leaflet

In HTML I have got 8 countries that return information in a separate `<div>` with an ajax/curl coded API.

when one country is selected, my leaflet map is supposed to map.flyTo the location of that country.

I have tried the following:

```js
var optionValue = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

var currentLocation = map.getBounds();
var bahamasLocation = L.latLngBounds(25.025885, -78.035889);
var japanLocation = L.latLngBounds(36.2048, 138.2529)


function moveMap() {
  if (!currentLocation.equals(bahamasLocation) && (optionValue = "Bahamas")) {
    map.flyTo([25.025885, -78.035889], 10)
  } else if (!currentLocation.equals(japanLocation) && (optionValue = "Japan")) {
    map.flyTo([36.2048, 138.2529], 10);
  }

  //     // switch(optionValue){
  //     //     case "Bahamas":
  //     //         map.flyTo([25.025885, -78.035889], 10);
  //     //     break;

  //     //     case "Japan":
  //     //         map.flyTo([36.2048, 138.2529], 10);
  //     //     break;
  //     // }
}

document.getElementById('btnRun').onclick = moveMap();
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <select id="selCountry">
    <!--country to "select-->
    <option>Select a Country</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland
    </option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btnRun">Let's go!</button>
</div>
```

I have tried different ways of writing it but am very unsure of what I'm doing wrong. help?

Comment: The method is called `panTo` and it will only "fly" to the location if the target location is close enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. The `optionValue` has a changeable value, and it should be set within the `moveMap()` function. Also, you were originally retrieving a collection of HTML elements (options), and not just the selected option (which is what you need). The example below handles things differently - first, `select` element is retrieved, and then, within it, the selected option is found, and its `text` used for flying to a specific location
2. The same thing goes for the `currentLocation`, since it can change after the document (and the map) have been loaded.
3. It would be better if the `click` event handler is attached to the button via `element.addEventListener("click", moveMap)`
4. You don't have to, but you could also add the coordinates and individual zoom levels inside an object, or in `data-lat`, `data-lng`, `data-zoom` attributes, and read them from there, instead of using the `switch/case`. You will find an example of that below.

Below you will find a working example (edited to include suggestions from @tacoshy in the comments).

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([15, 15], 2);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

function moveMap(){
    var currentLocation = map.getBounds();
    var select = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    var optionValue = option.value;
    
    var lat = option.getAttribute('data-lat');
    var lng = option.getAttribute('data-lng');
    var zoom = option.getAttribute('data-zoom');
    
    if(lat && lng && zoom) {
        map.flyTo([lat, lng], zoom);
    }
}

document.getElementById('btnRun').addEventListener("click",moveMap);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>
<div class="navBar">
  <select id="selCountry">
    <!--country to "select-->
    <option>Select a Country</option>
    <option data-lat="25.02588" data-lng="-78.035889" data-zoom="10" value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option data-lat="" data-lng="" data-zoom="10" value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option data-lat="36.2048" data-lng="138.2529" data-zoom="10" value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option data-lat="" data-lng="" data-zoom="10" value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option data-lat="" data-lng="" data-zoom="10" value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option data-lat="" data-lng="" data-zoom="10" value="GL">Greenland
    </option>
    <option data-lat="" data-lng="" data-zoom="10"  value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option data-lat="" data-lng="" data-zoom="10"  value="US">United States</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btnRun">Let's go!</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Some notes:

- the example contains additional HTML and CDN linking of CSS and scripts, as well as map initialization (all of this wasn't in the code in your question)
- the example works for Bahamas and Japan, and doesn't handle flying to other locations, as their coordinates were missing from your question

Comment: There are way more issues than you listed such as `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTML Collection Object. Using a switch case where you compare the entire object can't work nor would it be working with more selects. However, you could bypass that issue with a nice simple approach by using data attributes which unfortunately you only recommended instead of utilizing. Utilizing could have cut down the JS code to 5-10 lines.

Comment: @tacoshy Regarding the `getElementsByTagName` - this was actually addressed in the code, in the way the selected option was retrieved. Though, admittedly, I should have mentioned that explicitly in the response (will update). Regarding the `data` attributes - you are correct. I left it as a recommendation only, since I have no idea how the OP is populating the `select` element with options (DB, reading from a JSON file, etc). Will update that as well, and show how it would be done with `data` attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked like a charm! I understand now what was wrong thank you very much for the explanation!